# What was the line that David Prowse said on Bespin set?

Tags: dialogue, star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

In various Star Wars documentaries it is mentioned that Mark Hamill and George Lucas were apparently the only two people on set who knew that James Earl Jones would eventually dub Vader with the famous "Luke, I am your father" line. David Prowse actually had a different line in his script.

Is it documented anywhere what that line was? What did he say that was equally deserving of Luke's reaction?

Comment: "Luke, I am your mother." NO-o-o-o-o! That's Impossible!

Comment: The famous quote is actually, "No, I am your father."

Comment: The line spoken by James Earl Jones is actually, "No, I am your father."  This is almost always misquoted, as in your question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe he actually said, "Obi-Wan killed your father."

I'll go find some proof.

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_V:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back#Production):

> In the original film, Skywalker is told by Obi-Wan Kenobi that his
>   father, Anakin Skywalker, was betrayed and murdered by Kenobi's own
>   apprentice, Darth Vader. However, in The Empire Strikes Back, Vader
>   himself reveals that he is actually Anakin. According to director
>   Irvin Kershner, the shooting script had a false page with Vader's
>   dialogue implicating Kenobi as the murderer of Luke's father, but at
>   the time, only he, George Lucas, screenwriter Lawrence Kasdan, and
>   producer Gary Kurtz were privy to the knowledge that Vader and Anakin
>   were to be the same person.
>
> Moments before the scene was filmed, Mark Hamill, the actor playing
>   Luke, was taken aside privately and told the truth by Kershner, who
>   encouraged him to ignore the dialogue Prowse was speaking and "use
>   your own rhythm compared to what he's doing". During filming, Prowse
>   performed the false lines, while the real lines were later spoken by
>   James Earl Jones in post production – the majority of the cast,
>   including Prowse, were not aware of this plot twist until the first
>   screening of the finished film; at the premiere of the film, Prowse
>   was taken aback, and spoke privately to Kershner later, saying that he
>   (in Kershner's words) "would have done it differently" had he known of
>   the twist. In later years, Prowse claimed he would sometimes deliver
>   joke versions of his lines in Empire and Jedi, knowing that the vocal
>   takes would not be used.

Comment: I should point out that I've been doing some more digging, and several sites seem to think that he said "Obi-Wan IS your father," instead of 'KILLED'. I'm a bit of a geek, and am pretty sure it was actually 'killed', unless someone wants to offer up viable evidence to the contrary.

Comment: I agree - 'Killed' makes much more sense than 'Is'

Comment: @Nobby I don't know it, but I think the "killed" version makes more sense, as the other crew on the set would surely have wondered about Luke's heavy reaction to the "is" version, since he really liked Obivan.

Comment: It's quite a nice in world line as well as Vader would blame Obi Wan for the "death" of Anakin